# Golang - split string into at most N parts?

Tags: string, go, split

**Code & problem**

```
// parse request,
parts := strings.Split(message, ",")
uuid := parts[0]
data := parts[1]
```

The above code split `message` by `,`, I actually want 2 parts.
But the *data* part itself may contain `,`, so it may be split into more than 2 parts.

---

**e.g**

I want to split string:
`"19177360-2765-4597-a58e-519783a0d51d,a,b,c"`
into:
[`"19177360-2765-4597-a58e-519783a0d51d"`, `"a,b,c"`]
**not**:
[`"19177360-2765-4597-a58e-519783a0d51d"`, `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`]

---

**Possible solution**

With `strings.Split(message, ",")`, it split into 4 parts.
I can search for first `,`, then get substrings by hand.

---

**Question**

But is there a convenient function to specify the max `N` parts to split the string into.

`Java` has such built-in methods for `String`, is there similar `Go` libraries for `string` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strings.SplitN`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#SplitN) is the function that you wants, the third parameter is the number of parts that you want to split:

```
arrayString := strings.SplitN(message, ",", 2)
// arrayString[0] = 19177360-2765-4597-a58e-519783a0d51d
// arrayString[1] = a,b,c
```